# magento2 category (product listing page not working)

Tags: magento2, category, products

```
 1 exception(s): Exception #0
 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method
 Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor::isLoggedIn

 Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid
 method Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor::isLoggedIn
 #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor.php(921):
 Magento\Framework\DataObject->__call('isLoggedIn', Array)
 #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\loginbutton.phtml(4):
 Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor->__call('isLoggedIn',
 Array)
 #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\loginbutton.phtml(4):
 Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor->isLoggedIn()
 #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59):
 include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
 #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(260):
 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor),
 'C:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
 #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor.php(167):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
 #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(284):
 Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor->fetchView('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
 #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
 #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor.php(479):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
 #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542):
 Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor->toHtml()
 #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('skip_to_content...')
 #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('skip_to_content...')
 #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('skip_to_content...')
 #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('skip_to_content...',
 true)
 #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('skip_to_content...')
 #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('after.body.star...')
 #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('after.body.star...')
 #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('after.body.star...')
 #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('after.body.star...',
 true)
 #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('after.body.star...')
 #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
 #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
 #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
 #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
 #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(938):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
 #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
 #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(494):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput',
 Array, Array)
 #27 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(243):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
 #28 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(164):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #29 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #30 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult',
 Array)
 #31 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63):
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...',
 'renderResult',
 Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array,
 'result-varnish-...')
 #32 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin.php(74):
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #33 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67):
 Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor),
 Object(Closure),
 Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #34 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138):
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...',
 'renderResult',
 Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array,
 'result-builtin-...')
 #35 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin.php(67):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #36 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142):
 Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor),
 Object(Closure),
 Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #37 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
 Array, Array)
 #38 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139):
 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
 #39 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258):
 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
 #40 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test2\index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
 #41 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have custom theme/module that calls isLoggedIn in `loginbutton.phtml` template on the wrong block.